# Syslog info from vmware hosts to graylog are not collecting correctly

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, syslog, graylog

I have a [graylog syslog](http://graylog2.org/) server running on debian, running fine. I wanted to send syslogs from our Vmware ESX hosts to Graylog. I point a ESX host to the syslog by doing the following:

I open vSphere Client and selected my host. And then I select configuration... advanced settings, scroll down and expand Syslog and select global. Now under Syslog.global.loghost I put my server info-> udp://ipaddressofgraylog2:514 
And I open the firewall for the syslog. Everything works at this end.

I go to my Graylog Server, and I see a ton of data being sent over. I adjust the host syslog output-> vCenter, select a host in the inventory, then the Configuration tab -> Advanced Settings -> Config -> HostAgent -> Log. Set logging level to "Error" (for now).

My problem:
I look closer at Graylog "HOSTS":[image]

Graylog has 31 hosts listed, but there are really just 7 hosts. The syslog info from the ESX host(s) are not for a  better word "tidy". My question is how I can make it "tidy"? If I have 3-4 ESX hosts sending their syslogs like this, parsing the info would be brutal.

Is this a graylog problem?
Vmware ESX v5.5 problem?

**ANSWER from mrlesmithjr** [link](http://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/ubuntu-12-04-graylog2-installation)/[script](https://github.com/mrlesmithjr/graylog2/blob/master/install_graylog2_preview_ubuntu.sh)!

```
# Now we need to modify some things to get rsyslog to forward to graylog. this is useful for ESXi syslog format to be correct.
echo "Updating graylog2.conf and rsyslog.conf"
sed -i -e 's|syslog_listen_port = 514|syslog_listen_port = 10514|' /etc/graylog2.conf
sed -i -e 's|#$ModLoad immark|$ModLoad immark|' /etc/rsyslog.conf
sed -i -e 's|#$ModLoad imudp|$ModLoad imudp|' /etc/rsyslog.conf
sed -i -e 's|#$UDPServerRun 514|$UDPServerRun 514|' /etc/rsyslog.conf
sed -i -e 's|#$ModLoad imtcp|$ModLoad imtcp|' /etc/rsyslog.conf
sed -i -e 's|#$InputTCPServerRun 514|$InputTCPServerRun 514|' /etc/rsyslog.conf
sed -i -e 's|*.*;auth,authpriv.none|#*.*;auth,authpriv.none|' /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
echo '$template GRAYLOG2,"<%PRI%>1 %timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %FROMHOST% %syslogtag% - %APP-NAME%: %msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"' | tee /etc/rsyslog.d/32-graylog2.conf
echo '$ActionForwardDefaultTemplate GRAYLOG2' | tee -a  /etc/rsyslog.d/32-graylog2.conf
echo '$PreserveFQDN on' | tee -a  /etc/rsyslog.d/32-graylog2.conf
echo '*.info @localhost:10514' | tee -a  /etc/rsyslog.d/32-graylog2.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Logman. I would recommend you head over to the following site and get graylog2 up and running correctly to clean up your vSphere hosts syslog when importing into graylog2. Stand up a Ubuntu vm and install from scratch.

http://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/ubuntu-12-04-graylog2-installation

Comment: This syslog was made for testing, and I did have a couple window servers sending thier logs to it and it was working fine with the Windows servers. My test syslog server was based on that link.

Comment: How long ago did you use that install link? That is my site and script which makes me think it had been a while seeing as it does not have any pruning.

Comment: see if there is a /etc/rsyslog.d/32-graylog2.conf file. If not create it or if there is edit it to only contain the following. $template GRAYLOG2,"<%PRI%>1 %timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %FROMHOST% %syslogtag% - %APP-NAME%: %msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
$ActionForwardDefaultTemplate GRAYLOG2
$PreserveFQDN on
*.info @localhost:10514

Comment: Then do the following to clean up all old messages and hosts to get a fresh start.
cd /opt/elasticsearch/data/graylog2
sudo rm -rf *
mongo
use graylog2
db.message_counts.remove()
db.hosts.remove()
exit
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart